# Maintain Sharepoint Server Url with subfolders in document list

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint, listobject

I want to iterate through Sharepoint document library items (files and folder and subfolders) then print every folder content in Excel sheet

I've the following code in my Macro

```
Sub WriteFileProp(mySourcePath As String)

    Dim objMyList As ListObject
    Dim objWksheet As Worksheet
    Dim strSPServer As String
    Dim SERVER As String
    Const LISTNAME As String = "Documents"
    Const VIEWNAME As String = ""
     SERVER = mySourcePath
   ' The SharePoint server URL pointing to
   ' the SharePoint list to import into Excel.

    strSPServer = "http:" & SERVER & "/_vti_bin"
    ' Add a new worksheet to the active workbook.
    Set objWksheet = Worksheets.Add
    ' Add a list range to the newly created worksheet
    ' and populated it with the data from the SharePoint list.
    Set objMyList = objWksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcExternal, _
        Array(strSPServer, LISTNAME, VIEWNAME), False, , Range("A1"))

 End Sub
```

and that function

```
 Dim objFSO As Object
 Dim objFolder As Object
 Dim ObjFile As Object
 Dim SubFolder As Object
 Dim pth As String
 Dim WBn As Workbook
 Dim ObCount As Long
 Dim FileNme As String

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

 'Get the folder object associated with the directory
 Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("//S1.S2.S3Portal/Shared%20Documents/")

 Call WriteFileProp("S1.S2.S3Portal.com/")
 'Print main view

For Each SubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
            Call WriteFileProp(SubFolder.Path)
        Next
```

Everything works properly until `Call WriteFileProp("S1.S2.S3Portal.com/")`
After that I loop for subfolders and the path isn't compatible with
ServerUrl that's provided in

```
objWksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcExternal, _
        Array(strSPServer, LISTNAME, VIEWNAME), False, , Range("A1"))
```

i.e. lets say the first subfolder name is Software its path is in the following format 
[//S1.S2.S3Portal/Shared%20Documents/Software](http:////S1.S2.S3Portal/Shared%20Documents/)

but ListObjects.Add accepts only that format according to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823155.aspx)

strSPServer = http://S1.S2.S3Portal

ListName= "Documents"

View=""

are there anyway to maintain subfolders Urls of that doc. library and add them to excel workbook using ListObjects.Add or similar function

Comment: From what I remember "Forms" is a special Sharepoint folder. I was keeping a count of uploaded Excel files and "Forms" was used only for internal processing, not as normal storage path so I bypassed it in all subfolders

Comment: @paulbica I've just mentioned any name , anyway I've modified it in the question in order to eliminate any confusion , Hope it helps

Comment: sorry for not getting back sooner; I don't have Sharepoint and I'm having a hard time understanding the issue without seeing what each step in the code is doing: you want to build a table object containing all the http addresses. You did some investigations trying to figure out why "Call WriteFileProp" fails, but "...path isn't compatible..." is not specific enough: the WriteFileProp Sub fails somewhere and you need to see the details of the error. I'm guessing it has to do with the http address string and the way Excel writes it to the table

Comment: try this: in the first Sub WriteFileProp, add the following as the first line after the function name: "On Error Resume Next", then add this line after the lines starting with "Set": MsgBox "Error details: " & Err.Description. Do you see and relevant details in the message box? (I'll use an answer for you to see what to try)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used GetListItems with Soap query and webservice to get list items instead of the posted method